# Error creating Dojox Tree grid in XPages

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages

I have been trying to create a tree grid on XPages and While rending the grid am getting "Sorry, an error occurred".

The JSON Strings below is what am trying to render:

```
var data = {"identifier": "name",
 "label": "name",
items: [
    {"name": "Africa", "": "continent", "children": "[
            { "name":"Egypt", "field":"country" },
            { "name":"Kenya", "field":"country", "children":"[
                { "name":"Nairobi", "field":"city" },
                { "name":"Mombasa", "field":"city" } ]"
            ]},
            { "name":"Sudan", "field":"country", "children":"[
                { "name":'Khartoum', "field":"city" }]"
            },
        { "name":'Asia', "field":"continent", "children":"[
            { "name":"China", "field":"country" },
            { "name":"India", "field":"country"},
            { "name":"Russia", "field":"country" },
            { "name":"Mongolia", "field":"country" } ]"
        }

     }
]}
```

The below Dojo code including the var above is are in the  onCleintLoad event- Cleint side:

```
var jsonStore = new ItemFileWriteStore({data:data});

var layout = [
     {name: "Continent",     field: "continent"},
     {name: "Country",     field: "country"}  

];  

var treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
  store: folderStore,
  query: {type:'name'},
  rootId: 'LandRoot',
  rootLabel: 'Land',
  childrenAttrs: ['children']
});

var grid = new dojox.grid.TreeGrid({
  treeModel: treeModel,
  structure: layout,
  showRoot: true 
}, 'treeGrid');

grid.startup();

dojo.connect(window, "onresize", grid, "resize");
```

Comment: Is there any further error message visible in Firebug?

Comment: no, and now its just blank no error message but a empty page

Comment: Have you been able to confirm the onClientLoad event runs *before* the DojoTreeGrid tries to draw the contents?

Comment: I tried it on chrom the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: That would imply an error with your JSON data

Comment: Now it run without error it show the first row which is the heading and the content remain blank i tried to print out the data value on screen its show [object Object]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86866/discussion-between-simon-peter-and-paul-stephen-withers).

Comment: You'll need to debug the code and identify the error. If someone can see an obvious error in your code above, that may resolve the problem. Other than that I cannot help identify your error. My use of client-side JavaScript is minimal and the experience I have of Dojo Tree Grid in http://xhelp.openntf.org was via declarative markup not javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by add a new value `"level":"0"` to the String at the begining of every new category:

```
{"level": 0,"name": "Africa", "": "continent", "children": "[.....
```

and at the ForestStoreModel for the grid:

```
var treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
  store: folderStore,
  query: {type:'name'},
  rootId: 'LandRoot',
  rootLabel: 'Land',
  childrenAttrs: ['children']
});
```

I change the query property  which is required to select the category items to `query: {level:"0"},`. That is the line cursing the error because .`type:'name'`  did not exist in the JSONString.